# Integral of square root of the ratio of polynomials

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I would like to compute 
$$ \int_0^1 \sqrt{\frac{ (1 + \omega)x^2 + \omega x + \omega^2}{(1-x)x(x + \omega)^2}} dx $$ 
in closed form for $\omega \in \mathbb{R}^+$.
I have tried a couple things, such as differentiating under the integral sign and looking for fruitful substitutions, but so far no luck. Maybe I'm missing something basic here.

If it can't be computed in closed form, I'd be content with showing that it can be computed at all (i.e. that the integral converges). To that end I reckon it is sufficient to show that the integral in question is bounded above by
$$\int_0^1 \sqrt{ \frac{ (1 + \omega) x^2}{(1-x)x(x + \omega)^2}} dx + \int_0^1 \sqrt{ \frac{\omega x}{(1-x)x(x + \omega)^2}} dx + \int_0^1\sqrt{ \frac{ \omega^2 }{(1-x)x(x + \omega)^2}} dx$$
which evaluate to
$$-\dfrac{{\pi}\left(\sqrt{\omega^2+\omega}-\omega-1\right)}{\sqrt{\omega+1}} -\dfrac{\sqrt{\omega}\ln\left(-\frac{2\sqrt{\omega+1}-\omega-2}{\omega}\right)}{\sqrt{\omega+1}} + \dfrac{{\pi}\sqrt{\omega^2+\omega}}{\omega+1}.$$
I'd be grateful if someone could tell me whether this is correct, too.

Comment: (I) you seem to have both $w$ and $\omega$ in the first integral after the title (II) is $\omega$ a real number? If not, is it a cube root of unity?

Comment: @WillJagy typos fixed and info added, thanks.

Comment: alright. In the corrected integral, you still have $x$ as a common factor in the numerator and $x^2$ in the denominator. Usually we would cancel.

Comment: The antiderivative can be computed leading to a huge number of various elliptic integrals. The problem is to take the limit when $x\to 0$ and $x\to 1$.

Comment: Out of curiosity: does it arise from some physical calculation (physics, engineering etc) or just pure maths?

Comment: @edmz The integrand is supposed to be a Jeffreys prior for the basic reproductive number $R_0$ in a particular model of stochastic transmission. I've derived the prior and now would like to prove it's _proper_, i.e., the integral can be computed to give a normalised probability density function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I imagine the first part is hopeless.  Even with $\omega=1$, Maple still gets big expressions with elliptic integrals where it cannot do the limit $x\to 1^-$.

For the second part.  To show the integral converges: the integrand is continuous on the open interval $(0,1)$, so we only have to determine the behavior at the endpoints.

For $x \to 0^+$ we have
$$
\sqrt{\frac{ (1 + \omega)x^2 + \omega x + \omega^2}{(1-x)x(x + \omega)^2}}
= \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} + O(1),
$$
and we know $$\int_0^\epsilon\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x}}$$ converges.
For $x \to 1^-$ we have
$$
\sqrt{\frac{ (1 + \omega)x^2 + \omega x + \omega^2}{(1-x)x(x + \omega)^2}}
= \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x}} + O(1)
$$
and
$$
\int_{1-\epsilon}^1\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-x}}
$$
converges.

Therefore, the integral converges.

Comment: thanks a lot for this. Would my argument, which uses $\sqrt{a_0 + a_1+ \ldots+ a_n} \leq \sqrt{a_0} + \sqrt{a_1} + \ldots + \sqrt{a_n}$ and linearity of integration, also be valid?